# How to access Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to firebase and android development, therefore, I have not totally understood how it works. I want to know if after adding project to firebase, does it mean the app is launched and will be accessible by anyone who have android or how do I tell someone to try the app when it has not been uploaded to playstore?

Answer (score 1):

[What is Firebase?](https://howtofirebase.com/what-is-firebase-fcb8614ba442)

In a simple way, firebase as a server and many more log details related to your app and user behavior. It's a complete package to monitor app, users and many more. It will also give you scope to build app without having your own server and also no need of any language.

*I want to know if after adding project to firebase, does it mean the app is launched*

No adding project does not mean your app has been published or launched, but you can see crashes, save data, authenticate and can use available features in firebase.

*and will be accessible by anyone*

What you want to make accessible? If it is app, then it will be only accessible to users when you publish app in play store in production. There are some other options such as alpha, beta, internal test - each of these have some own functionality. Here you can add users email ids as tester and invite them to test or about your app. When you have not published an APK in production mood it won't be visible publicly.

*how do I tell someone to try the app when it has not been uploaded to playstore*

After adding firebase project nothing mean to release/publish your app. Publishing in play store does mean that. Here I will suggest you upload your app APK in play store ALPHA/BETA/INTERNAL test release mood then add/invite people to test your app.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding Firebase with Play store console. Firebase is a BaaS (backend-as-a-Service). In simple language Firebase is platform which allow to build web and mobile applications without server side programming language.

Adding your android project to firebase have nothing to do with publishing app. It will not publish your app.
Play store console is what that is used to publish android apps.